# Transition height not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to create a simple CSS `transition` that changes the `height` and `width` of a square box. The `width` seems to be changing with animation but the `height` does not animate. How can I fix this? Or what am I doing wrong here?

```
p {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 200px; 
  transition: width 3s;
}

p:hover {
  width: 300px; 
  height 500px;
}
```

Comment: 'transition: **width** 3s' should indicate something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `transition` both `width` and `height` you must change the transition setting like below:

```
p {width: 100px; height: 200px; transition: all 3s;}
```

Your code was also missing a `:` in the `height` property setting within `p:hover`.

```
p:hover {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 500px; /* added missing : */
}
```

```css
p {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 3s;
}
p:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;  /* added missing : */
}
```

```html
<p>abcd</p>
```

As mentioned in [godfrzero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19336383/2606013), if you want to transition only `height` and `width` (but not any other property's value change) don't use the `all` method.

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure you only want to animate the `height` and `width` properties and not all CSS properties, you can also do this:

```
p:hover {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  transition: height, width linear 3s;
}
```

Your current CSS code only instructs the browser to animate the width.

Comment: +1. ah right, I was just about to state doing height and width alone, but now that you have added it, I have added it to my answer with a mention to your post. Hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to keep height at auto, I have found that using 
    max-height: auto;
for the element's ending state and 
    max-height: 0px 
(or whatever you start with) for the initial property keeps both the transition and auto height sizing.